# Create Laplace matrix, filter image

Tags: c++, math, image-processing

i'm doing a project that implements image filters. 
My problem is, the user say to apply a laplace filter in a image, the kernel is nxn size.
I know the laplace uses the following matrix 3x3:

```
0  1  0

1 -4  1

0  1  0
```

but if he wants a nxn matrix how do i create it?

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: I wonder how you create a filter laplace size nxn

Comment: Are you asking how to create a 2 dimensional array of a variable size in c++?

Comment: allocate a 2d array in C++?  read in a matrix from user input?  compute a laplace?  We're guessing at what you're asking here which is why your question is getting downvotes and close votes.

Comment: It's difficult to explain. My problem is how a nxn laplace matrix is form. Imagine, a 3x3 laplace matrix for imagem filter is
0  1 0

1 -4 1

0  1 0

and a 5x5 i think is

0 0  1 0 0

0 1  1 1 0

1 1 -12 1 1

0 1  1 1 0

0 0  1 0 0


I want create a nxn matrix according to this idea. My problem is the  mathematical formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Laplace filter" in image processing is called that because you can derive it exactly from the formal definition of the discrete Laplacian on graphs. This approach leads to two convolution kernels that immediately make sense,

```
1  1  1
1 -8  1
1  1  1
```

and

```
0  1  0
1 -4  1
0  1  0
```

, depending on whether you consider the diagonally adjacent pixels as neighbours or not.

You can of course use other matrices as convolution kernels (the convolution works exactly the same way, the operation is independent of matrix dimensions), but those are no longer "Laplacians". You can calculate larger convolution kernels that approximate other continuous operators, but imho there is no one "right definition" for an `nxn` Laplacian matrix.

Either rely on user input and trust the user to enter a sensible kernel for your purpose, or do some research into how to approximate other operators. An example for an approximation of a Laplacian-of-Gaussian is given here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm

Comment: uhmm now i understand. Tanks my friend ;)

Comment: user2052665 writes he has got it, but I haven't. I am, too, interested in a general method of generating Laplace kernels of arbitrary order (N*N), not in LoG kernels. I failed to find it in literature.

Comment: this answer is wrong. laplacian kernel is calculated based on the Taylor series expansion. and I'm not in the mood to calculate it here, but this answer is wrong, we have laplacian of any size you want, you just need to calculate more points dx in taylor series.